# .NET Core 2: How to check if the request is MIME multipart Content?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

In ASp.NET MVC, you can check if the current request is MIME multipart content. How to check that in .NET Core? I have an action filter to validate that, but not sure how to evaluate to request header. IsMimeMultipartContent is not available in .NET Core.

```
/// <summary>
/// Checks whether the current request specified content is MIME multipart content.
/// </summary>
/// <exception cref="HttpRequestException">Raised when the current request doesn't have MIME multipart content.</exception>
public class HasMimeMultipartContentAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            throw new HttpRequestException("This request does not contain any file to upload.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC Core uses the `IFormFile` interface to bind multipart HTTP requests. If the request does not use multipart/form-data, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads) states that the bound value will be null.

Comment: This is the right way. To check if the request has multipart boundry, the request property has a method called "GetMultipartBoundary()". If it returned null, it's a good check that request doesn't have any file in it.

Answer (score 9):

You can check that the request is multipart/form-data using property [HttpRequest.HasFormContentType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.hasformcontenttype?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Then the presence of files in the request using property [HttpRequest.Form.Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformcollection.files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_IFormCollection_Files)

Example:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{

    if (context.Request.HasFormContentType && context.Request.Form.Files.Any)
    {

    }
}
```