# HttpRequestMessage.Content alternative in .Net 5

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-5

I am migrating web app from .Net framework 4.6.1 to .Net 5

I have this code in controller(.Net 4.6.1):

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        return BadRequest("Unsupported media type");
    }
    return true;
}
```

I try to convert it to .Net 5 and faced error.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        return BadRequest("Unsupported media type");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Error -

> 'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Content'

What is the alternative for it in .Net 5 ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's recommended to use `IFormFile` interface for multipart requests in ASP.NET MVC Core and consequently in .net5 also. See Stackoverflow question: [.NET Core 2: How to check if the request is MIME multipart Content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45871479/net-core-2-how-to-check-if-the-request-is-mime-multipart-content)

But if you want to use your specific code snippet, you may refactor it as following:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
{
    if (!IsMultipartContentType(Request.ContentType))
    {
         return BadRequest("Unsupported media type");
    }
    return true;
}

//...

public static bool IsMultipartContentType(string contentType)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType)
         && contentType.IndexOf("multipart/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
}
```

(see [Microsoft documentation and examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0))