# How to get Content from Request in Controllerbase (NET. 6)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a question on how to access the Context in Request.
I would like to use the method:

```
Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent()
```

Thanks for helps.

Regards

Comment: Please give more context. Where are you trying to call this?

Comment: In .net core, I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60547374/7687666) should usful to you.  You should use the code in the link I provided to you.

Answer (score -1):

You have to get inheritance of your controller from BaseController.

Comment: Can I ask for an example?

Comment: Directly ask but your answer is above which I answered you.